# How to restore a time machine backup from a newer OS version?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I'm currently trying to downgrade my macOS from Mojave to High Sierra. I got High Sierra working without any problems. But the migration tool won't accept my time machine backup as it's from a newer OS version (it says that i have to upgrade the OS, but that's exactly what I don't want to do at all). How can I get all apps, settings, files and users from the backup on High Sierra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no surprise that Migration Assistant won't help you with this.

You can use the Time Machine UI (in the Finder) to restore your users' home directories.

For most apps, you'd be better off re-installing them from their installers, especially if they might not be self-contained. For example, apps sold outside of the App Store often come with installers that install a bunch of stuff in various places under /Library, and it would be hard to find all those files to restore them to your High Sierra environment.

For system settings, just set up all your settings again by hand.

The problem you're facing is that things like how settings are stored, how user account information is stored, how your Photos.app and Mail.app data is stored, how your Spotlight search metadata is stored, etc., often change from one major OS release to the next.

Apple writes the code in the new OS version to upgrade those settings and data to the new formats as applicable, but it's not cost-effective for anyone to write code for the old OS version to know how to downgrade settings that have already been migrated to the new version. It's just not a thing that enough people need to do often enough to be worth the software engineering work.

Beware that for built-in apps like Photos and Mail that store their data in proprietary, undocumented database-like formats, you might have problems downgrading. For example, if you already launched Mail or Photos under Mojave and those apps already updated their databases, then when you try to use the High Sierra versions of those apps, they might not know what to do with the new format and may just fail to work with it or may corrupt it.

Comment: Yup. The only real way to do this is to have a backup from before the update. Anything else is pretty much doomed to failure, Mail especially. I'm really not sure why anyone would want to go back to the hideously buggy Sierras anyway. Mojave ain't perfect, but it's better than either of the Sierras :P

Comment: @Tetsujin APFS on a Mid-2013 MacBook Air is the reason: made it feel not 7 but 14 years old. I highly recommend everyone not to go over High Sierra (and disable APFS conversion!!)  with that model or before.